# What does this Javascript do? `new Function("_", "at" , "with(_) {return (" + text + ");}" )`

Tags: javascript

What is this line doing:

```
  var tfun = new Function("_", "at" , "with(_) {return (" + text + ");}" );
```

What is the `_`, `at`, and `with(_)`?

I've read this:
http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsFunc/index.html

I understand that it's creating a new function object, but am still quite puzzled at what his is supposed to do.

Forgot to put the source:
http://kite.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kite.js

http://www.terrainformatica.com/2011/03/the-kite-template-engine-for-javascript/

Comment: The important part is actually `text`. `_` and `at` are just the parameters the function has (like `function tfun(_, at) {}`) and you can read more about `with` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Comment: Where did you find this monstrosity?

Comment: @CD can't believe I forgot to include the source, edited.
@Felix Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a function is being created that will return the value of the key stored in the variable `text` on the object passed in to `tfun()`.

When a `new Function` is created in this manner, the first arguments refer to the parameters of the function and the last argument is the function itself.  So here we have two parameters named `_` and `at` and then the function body.

`with()` is a statement saying to conduct the following lines of code within the context of the object specified.  So `with(_)` is saying to conduct the return statement pulling the key `text` stored in `_`.

Here's an example:

```
var text = "name";
var obj  = { "name" : "Bob" };

var tfun = new Function("_", "at" , "with(_) {return (" + text + ");}" );

tfun( obj ); // returns "Bob"
```

I'm not sure why the `at` parameter is there as it's not being used.

Comment: `text` may contain a reference to `at` which is horrible.

Answer (score 0):

First comes the function arguments, then code code, so it's basically the same as:

```
var tfun = function(_, at) {
  with(_) { return (eval(text)); };
}
```

So, whatever is in the `text` variable will be evaluated and returned from the function.

Note: The use of the `eval` function should generally be avoided, and as creating code dynamically from a variable does the same thing, it should also generally be avoided. There are a few situations where `eval` is needed, but most of the time it's not, so you should instead try find out the proper way of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, i added the source. Would you say the source is doing it inappropriately?

Comment: The use of `with` should also generally be avoided.

Comment: Both answers are really helpful, I would check you too if I could, thanks